# Net mvc4 form2 being submitted with empty model after form1 posts on the same page successfully returning data to the same model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using one form with two form posts in it. The first form ("frmTemps") successfully retreieves data and displys it on the form. I can assure you that via debugging the data is in the model when coming back to the View to display the data.

Once the data comes back, another button is displayed on the same View, but a second form ("frmProcess") to to some processing on the seclectd data coming back from the first form ("frmTemps"). I know you can have multiple forms on the sme View. It's all part of the control that MVC gives you.

The problem is that as soon as I post my second form ("**frmProcess**") **and have a breakpoint set immediately in that action result** and I check the contents of the model, I find out that **all the items in the model are either null, zero, or false.** Via debugging on the model object.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors model) {
```

I'm using the same model in form2 as I am in form 1.

I thought is was understood that after filling out data on a form and after submitting it and having your model type receive it in the action method, this is the standard way to do things.

Below, is my ViewModel.

```
public partial class ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors
{
    public int SelectedTemplateId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PDFTemplate> Templates { get; set; }

    public int SelectedGuarantorId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tGuarantor> Guarantors { get; set; }

    public string LoanId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDeptText { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDeptValue { get; set; }
    public string LoanType { get; set; }

    public bool ShowTemps { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string ErrorT { get; set; }
    public string ErrorG { get; set; }
    public bool ShowGeneratePDFBtn { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my View:

```
@model PDFConverterModel.ViewModels.ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BHG :: PDF Generator";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<div>

    <table style="width: 1000px">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <img alt="BHG Logo" src="~/Images/logo.gif" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Refresh", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmTemps" }))
        {  
            <tr>
                <td>
                @*@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<int>()
                        .Name("txtLoanID")
                        .Placeholder("Enter numeric value")
                )*@

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoanId)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoanId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoanId)
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="submit" id="btnRefresh" value='Refresh' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.LoanType)
                    @Html.TextBox("SBA", "SBA")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LoanType)
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoanType)*@
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="ddlDept">Department:</label>
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDeptText)
                            .Name("ddlDept")
                            .DataTextField("DepartmentName")
                            .DataValueField("DepartmentID")
                            .Events(e => e.Change("Refresh"))
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetDepartments", "Home");
                                });
                            })
                    )
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedDeptText)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

        @using (Html.BeginForm("GeneratePDF", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmProcess" }))
        {
            if (Model.ShowGeneratePDFBtn == true)
            {
                if (Model.ErrorT != string.Empty)
                {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <u><b>@Html.Label("Templates:")</b></u>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Templates)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.IsChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TemplateName)
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    Model.Error = Model.ErrorT;
                }

                if (Model.ErrorG != string.Empty)
                {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <u><b>@Html.Label("Guarantors:")</b></u>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Guarantors)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.isChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorFirstName)&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.GuarantorLastName)
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
                }
                else
                {
                    Model.Error = Model.ErrorG;
                }
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnGeneratePDF" value='Generate PDF' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Model.Error
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('btnRefresh').on('click', '#btnRefresh', function () {
        Refresh();
    });

    function Refresh() {

        var LoanID = $("#LoanID").val();

        if (LoanID != "") {
            document.forms["frmTemps"].submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Below, is my pertinent part of the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GeneratePDF(ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors **model**)
        {
            try
            {
                int FolderNo, GuarantorNum = 0;
                string Folder, LoanFolder = String.Empty;
                string FormId, FormName, GuarantorName = String.Empty;

                int LoanId = Convert.ToInt32(model.LoanId);
                LoanFolder = LoanId.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');

                //To calculate FolderId based on LoanId
                if ((LoanId > 0) && (LoanId < 99000))
                {
                    FolderNo = ((int)(LoanId / 10000) * 10000);
                }
                else
                {
                    FolderNo = ((int)(LoanId / 1000) * 1000);
                }

                Folder = ((int)FolderNo).ToString();
                Folder = Folder.PadLeft(8, '0');
```

I submitted form `A` through button 1. The model came back and populated my `View A`. Now I want to submit `View A` again with button 2 to a different Action method in the same controller.

When I submit the form again to the same Controller with my Model as the receiving parameter, my model is empty when it gets to the action method. I know my model has data in it when it came back above in the first step.

Being relatively new to MVC, I am under the impression that if your View is populated with data and you submit your form to a Controller, you Model should have data in it. I realize now, that the Model is not persistent. Once you pass the Model to the View and vice-versa, it's gone. I get it.

All I want to find out is how can I populate my model with data before I submit it to the Controller so it sends data to the Controller with my Model populated to render a View? It's that simple. Not ehtat my model is a strongly typed Model. I feel that this is a major cornerstone to understanding how I can submit data back & forthe between Views & Controllers and is very important to the understanding of how MVC works.

What am I doing wrong where my data is empty when it gets to my Controller again. How do I get the data from the View back inside the Model before I submit where my Model will have data in it in order to do some processing and render the View again.

If there is data that already resides on the form from the previous postback, then when I post again via the second button, why doesn't MVC use the model binder to create my model with the form data and post it.

I know the loanid and ddl won't be in the data (because it's not wrapped around the second form), but I am very perplexed in the way it works. I was expecting it to post the data back that resides on the form into the model. Why doesn't it do this?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the forms share a model the only values that will be submitted to the GeneratePDF action are those which are included in the "frmProcess" form. If you need to resubmit the values from "frmTemps" (e.g. LoanId)  to the GeneratePDF action then they will need to be included in the "frmProcess" form as hidden fields.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoanId)
```

Thus your data flow is:

- Populate values in "frmTemps"
- Post data from "frmTemps" to "Refresh" action
- Return view with updated model
- Values in updated model are populated as hidden fields in "frmProcess"
- Post all data from "frmProcess" to "GeneratePDF" action

Comment: So, your're saying that the model values in my second form (even though they were populated) actually don't go into the model? So, I won't be able to access all the fields in the second form from within my model. Are all of them actually automatically populated as hidden fields? IN my second form, therre are two collections of objects I have in there. How would they be represented as hidden fields? If this is possible, then once I submit the form, I need to access the data in the FormCollection object rather than my model?

Comment: Not you, but this seems a lame way to go that I thought would be one of the advantages of MVC by passing a model around and not worrying about viewstate. 

How should the receiving signature of the method look instead of public ActionResult GeneratePDF(ViewModelTemplate_Guarantors model)? 

I mean anothe advantage of mvc is having control of having multiple buttons on a form to submit (yes, with just that form data surronded by the using statement that would get submitted). What would be the best way to proceed underthis scenario?

Comment: I mean, it seems like the model is useless for the button that has the second button, which for me, almost totally defeats the purpose of using MVC.

Comment: @sagesky36 - MVC still must use Html and Http.  MVC doesn't magically pass things around, It can only do so via standard html form fields.  You have to understand that when you pass a model to a view, *NOTHING* in that view is sent back to the post even unless you make sure there is a form field for it.  Each request is a separate entity, and other than Session, there is no connection between one request and another except for what form field values are posted.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to keep in mind.

First, a form will only post the values that are within the submitted form elements.  If you have multiple forms on a page, then the data from other forms does not post.  Only the data from the "active" form.

If you want to round trip data, that is, post data then return a form, then when the second form is posted include the original data (even if it's the same view) then you need to have elements to hold that data so it will be posted again in the new form.  Hidden fields are often used for this purpose.

Finally, it's usually better to have separate views rather than combining multiple forms on a single page.  You can do this, and it makes sense in some situations (like having a search box on a page), but in general it's confusing.

Comment: Yes, I understand that first part. That's self explanatory... So, again, I would have to place all hiden fields in the second form instead of just hav ing them in the model? What about the 2 objects I have that are collections that were passed back to me via the first post (using the first button)? So, I would need to assign the values from the model to hidden fields? Again, what about my IEnumerable object collection with the foreach statements? If I do use a second View, can I leave the data in the model and simply pass the model to the action method?

Comment: @sagesky36 - The model in MVC is a mechanism that works for a single request (a single get or a single post) and allows you to pass a collection of data between the controller and the view.  Once the request is finished, the model is gone. Just because you pass a model to a view does not mean that model will be there on post back. The only thing that allows it to be there on post back is if there are post variables for each of the data items.  What's more, you can't post IEnumerable items, because IEnumerable is read-only.  You would have to post those values to something like a List or array.

Comment: @sagesky36 - You have some very incorrect assumptions about how MVC works.  MVC is strictly a server-side technology.  But that technology uses standard Html and Http as an intermediary between requests.  So anything you do in MVC has to be compatible with standard Html/Http.

Comment: Ah, I see... I thought the model was persistent bewtween the View and Controller... I should have know better when dealing with the web and http; not like SessionState... So, how would I post my List variables (which are the list of checkboxes) to my action method?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, when the model i posted back from the server for display and I know I have to send that data back again (after the user select which text boxes, etc), what's the best way to add that data again back into the model for a second post to a diffeent action method?

Comment: @sagesky36 - I'm still not fully clear on what you're doing and why, so it would be hard for me to suggest anything.

Comment: Look, in webforms, there is something that is called viewstate that keeps the value of the data on the form for subsequent submissions. With mvc, all i'm saying is tht it seems you need to manually pull the data from the form, stick it back inside the model and post it.  So, would you then just take the value of the data in the form and set it to your model for subsequent submission? in other words, model.loanid = form.loanid.

Comment: If this is the case, how would you also put complex data like a collection of checkboxes that are selected on a form back into the model for subsequent submission to another view (or the same view for that matter).

Comment: Based on what I'm experiencing, I don't know how much simpler I can tell my problem based on my previous code.